# Ruby: How can I get all the key elements from an json format?

Tags: ruby

I am new on ruby, i am not faimilar with the code block...
How can I get all the key element in an json format text?

```
text= "[{ "name" : "car", "status": "good"},
{ "name" : "bus", "status": "bad"},{ "name" : "taxi", "status": "soso"}]"
```

From the text, it is a string with json like format, 
how can i extract the name value only and input into an array

desired output ==>
[car, bus, taxi]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to parse the JSON data first:

```
require('json')

text = '[{ "name" : "car", "status": "good"}, { "name" : "bus", "status": "bad"},{ "name" : "taxi", "status": "soso"}]'
data = JSON.parse(text)
```

Then you can simply collect the items:

```
p data.collect { |item| item['name'] }
```

If you don't have name for every item and you want a default value instead:

```
p data.collect { |item| item.fetch('name', 'default value') }
```

If you want just skip them:

```
p data.collect { |item| item['name'] }.compact
```

Comment: thx it seems work, if one of the item doesn't not contain ["name"], how can I guard that as well?